# Creating events in Yahoo calendar

Tags: java, calendar, yahoo, jackrabbit, ical4j

I have been trying to create an event in my yahoo calendar for which I am using caldev specification, Http clients 3,Apache Jackrabbit and ical4J API.

I am able to create the event(getting 201 http response), retrieve the same event(using http get method) and can delete the same event.

The only problem I am facing is the event when created to the server it is not shown on the yahoo calendar.

I dont know what to do ... please guide me to correct direction.

Here is he event I am creating

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Test //iCal4j 1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20111103T011552Z
UID:f0266444-61ae-40ea-bf7d-e03b0f9a1fc3
SUMMARY:Tests Uploading Summary Event
DESCRIPTION:Tests Uploading Description Event
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20111103
URL:test.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CalDAV you may want to check out the ical4j-connector, which provides a Java API for communicating with CalDAV servers. You can find more details in the ical4j wiki:

http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Connector